# Tensorflow LSTM: Training accuracy very low and unchanging

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I thought about using a Tensorflow MNIST LSTM for a chemical reaction environment. Everything is similar to the MNIST concept as i am logging information for each past 30 minutes for 16 features. I considered it as something similar to a MNIST digit database with 30x16 size.

This is my repo:  https://github.com/lebbroth/tensorflow_lstm

I modified a lot from the following repo:  [TensorFlow-Examples/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py](http://tensorflow_MNIST) so i can be able to use CSV files instead of the raw MNIST dataset. I updated also the RNN functions by introducing variable_scopes.

The problem: I succeded finally to lunch a Tensorflow session but the training accuracy is very low and unchanged. What could be the cause of that? Should my data features be normalized? or I should look into something else?

Comment: Hi! RNNs can be very difficult to train withouth having lots of data (even LSTMs). Do you have enough 30-min blocks? I'll try to give it a look this weekend, page 410 of this link may be a good start http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/rnn.html

Comment: @fr_andres i think i did something dumb. My data should be rescaled between -1 and 1. I think the lstm is saturating. I have around 600 samples of 30 minutes each.

Comment: Ah! then maybe adding a `batch_norm` layer can help? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm.md

Comment: I don't know if there is something similar for LSTMs, I'll check it too... morrow

Comment: @fr_andres ok now i get it. I shouldn't normalize my data between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1. I should normalize based on the min and max as my features have totally independent nature from each other unlike MNIST where the features in an LSTM are practically similar to each other. So i will reduce my numbers and scale them accordingly.

Comment: does it already work? what was it?

Comment: @fr_andres i just finished normalizing my data now. I'll try to train in a while and update u.

Comment: @fr_andres it's not working still, with the normalized data.